# Logo not showing at the right spot on title page

Tags: graphics, positioning

What is wrong with my code? I'm trying to have the logo showing up at the top left corner.

Thanks

[image: Title page]

```
\newcommand*{\couverture}{\begingroup % Create the command for including the title page in the document
\pagestyle{empty}

%logo at 45 degres top left corner
    \includegraphics[scale = 1,angle=45,origin=c,trim = 0.62in .75in 0.38in 1.25in, ]{LogoCSTJ}
\hspace{\fill}
\rule{1pt}{\textheight} % Vertical line
\hspace*{0.05\textwidth} % Whitespace between the vertical line and title page text
\parbox[b]{0.45\textwidth}{ % Paragraph box which restricts text to less than the width of the page

\raggedright
{\noindent\Huge\bfseries \titre % Title
}\\[0.2\baselineskip] 
{\huge {\soustitre}} \\[0.5\baselineskip] % Subtitle

{\large \textit%{
\departement%} 
}\\[18\baselineskip]
{\large \textsc{Dans le cadre du cour :}}\\[\baselineskip]
{\Large \textsc{\cour} \\[0.35\baselineskip] \numcour} % Class name and number

\vspace{0.25\textheight}
{%\large 
\textsc{Version:}  \large\textsc \version}\\[0.5\baselineskip] % version number
{\normalsize \textit \session}\\[0.5\baselineskip] % Semester 
{\large \cegep }% Cegep name + href to website
}

\endgroup}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the input, i'll put all of my code next time I ask a question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've set the `\parbox` vertical alignment - or anchor - to be on the `[b]`ottom and it's height is the entire `\textheight`. As such, the image's anchor - which is on the baseline is aligned with the bottom of the `\parbox` which sits at the bottom of the page.

The easiest way out of this, without changing your template too much, is to use

```
\raisebox{<height>}[0pt][0pt]{<logo>}
```

which should raise your `<logo>` by the amount `<height>`. The `[0pt][0pt]` optional arguments remove any vertical height/depth that may result from the raise.

In your particular instance, you could use for you your `<height>` (say)

```
\raisebox{\dimexpr\textheight-\height}[0pt][0pt]{%
  \includegraphics[
    scale=1,
    angle=45,
    origin=c,
    trim = 0.62in .75in 0.38in 1.25in]{LogoCSTJ}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're making a paragraph consisting of:

1. The rotated logo; the baseline is computed so that the image center doesn't move from the place it would be without rotation
2. A rule; the baseline is at the bottom of the rule
3. A `\parbox[b]`, whose baseline coincides with the baseline of the last item in the box.

Thus you can see that TeX respects the specifications, although the result is not what you wish to get.

If you want the top of the rotated box coincides with the top of the rule, you have to use one more `\parbox` and to raise (actually lower) the image.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\titre}{ShopTurnXP}
\newcommand{\soustitre}{Guide d'installation}
\newcommand{\departement}{D\'epartement de g\'enie m\'ecanique}
\newcommand{\cour}{Command Num\'erique II}
\newcommand{\numcour}{241-236-JR}
\newcommand{\version}{V1.0.8}
\newcommand{\session}{Automne 2016}
\newcommand{\cegep}{C\'egep de Saint-J\'er\^ome}

\newcommand*{\couverture}{%
  \clearpage
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  % start at the top
  \vspace*{-\topskip}\vspace{-\baselineskip}
  % start at the left margin
  \noindent
  %logo at 45 degres top left corner
  \raisebox{-\height}{%
    \includegraphics[angle=45,width=4cm]{example-image}%
  }%
  % fill
  \hspace{\fill}%
  \parbox[t][\textheight]{0.5\textwidth}{%
    \vspace{0pt}% sets the baseline at the top
    \rule{1pt}{\textheight}% Vertical line
    \hspace{-1pt}%
    \hspace{0.05\textwidth}% Whitespace between the vertical line and title page text
    \parbox[b][\textheight][s]{0.45\textwidth}{% 
      \raggedright

      \vspace*{\stretch{1}}

      {\Huge\bfseries\titre}% Title
      \\[0.2\baselineskip]
      {\huge\soustitre}\\[0.5\baselineskip] % Subtitle
      {\large\textit{\departement}}

      \vspace*{\stretch{2}}

      {\large\textsc{Dans le cadre du cour :}}\\[\baselineskip]
      {\Large\textsc{\cour}}\\[0.35\baselineskip]
      \numcour % Class name and number

      \vspace*{\stretch{2}}

      \textsc{Version: \version}\\[0.5\baselineskip] % version number
      \textit{\session}\\[0.5\baselineskip] % Semester 
      {\large \cegep }% Cegep name + href to website
      \par\vspace{0pt}
    }%
  }
}

\begin{document}

\couverture

\end{document}
```

The `geometry` package is loaded for convenience, and `showframe` is used just to show the text block boundaries. The outermost rectangle in the first picture below represents the text block, not the page.

The outer `\parbox` has a zero height item at the top, that sets its baseline; the inner `\parbox` has a zero height item at the bottom, so the descenders will not go below the rule.

Using `\vspace{\stretch{...}}` gives more flexible control over the separation of the blocks.

[image]

Here's the full page without the boundaries of the text block.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want? The trick is to put the graphic file in another `\parbox`, raise this box of `–\height` while making LaTeX believe it has  `0 height`, and finally to  top-align the `\parbox`es

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[noheadfoot, nomarginpar, centering]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\def\titre{ShopTurnXP}
\def\soustitre{Guide d’installation}
\def\departement{Département de génie mécanique}
\def\cour{Commande numérique II}
\def\numcour{241-236-JR}
\def\version{V 1.0.8}
\def\session{Automne 2016}
\def\cegep{\textsc{Cegep de Saint Jérôme}}

\newcommand*{\couverture}{\begingroup% Create the command for including the title page in the document
\thispagestyle{empty}

%logo at 45 degres top left corner
    \raisebox{-0.67\height}[0pt]{\parbox[t]{0.4\textwidth}{\includegraphics[scale = 1,angle=45,origin=c,trim = 0.62in .75in 0.38in 1.25in, ]{LogoCSTJ}}}
\hspace{\fill}
\rule[\dimexpr1.5\baselineskip-\textheight\relax]{1pt}{\textheight} % Vertical line
\hspace*{0.05\textwidth} % Whitespace between the vertical line and title page text
\parbox[t]{0.45\textwidth}{ % Paragraph box which restricts text to less than the width of the page

\raggedright
{\noindent\Huge\bfseries \titre % Title
}\\[0.2\baselineskip]
{\huge {\soustitre}} \\[0.5\baselineskip] % Subtitle

{\large \textit%{
\departement%}
}\\[18\baselineskip]
{\large \textsc{Dans le cadre du cour :}}\\[\baselineskip]
{\Large \textsc{\cour} \\[0.35\baselineskip] \numcour} % Class name and number
\\
\vspace{0.23\textheight}
{%\large
\textsc{Version:} \large\textsc \version}\\[0.5\baselineskip] % version number
{\normalsize \textit \session}\\[0.5\baselineskip] % Semester
{\large \cegep }% Cegep name + href to website
}

\endgroup}

\begin{document}

\couverture

\end{document}
```

[image]